# Save initiator in Chrome when saving as HAR

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to include the initiator information shown in chrome network tab in the developer bar when exporting as HAR, but I'm unable to find a way to do so. Is there any addon or work around to be able to save this information in HAR or any other format?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps there was a limitation with copying the **Initiator** data when you created the OP. Anyway, it is working fine now, using the latest version of Chrome: Version 67.0.3396.79 (Official Build) (64-bit).

To create the HAR file:

- In Chrome press **F12** to open **DevTools** then click on the **Network** tab.
- Verify that the **Initiator** column is being displayed. Turn it on if necessary.
- Verify that the **Recording** icon in the top left is on (i.e. It displays as a red circle).
- Check the **Preserve log** checkbox.
- Navigate to the desired URL.
- Right click and select **Save as HAR with content** from the context menu.

To display the content of the HAR file later:

- In Chrome press **F12** to open **DevTools** and click on the **Network** 
  tab.
- Select the HAR file you created earlier from your file system manager (e.g. Windows Explorer) and drag it to the **Network** panel. Chrome will prompt you to *Drag HAR files here*. See the [Release notes for Chrome 62](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#har-imports) for more details.
- The HAR file content, including the **Initiator** column, will be displayed.

Comment: The initiator column just says "Other" in Version 91.0.4472.106 (Official Build) (64-bit). I've tried this on multiple sites.